# If I use CreateEx( ... ) after the main window was created I cannot FindWindow( ... )

Tags: c++, c++11, findwindow

I have the following code to create a 'message only' window, the window is **always** created fine, the problem happens *when* it is created.

**Process A**

```
...
auto hInstance = ::GetModuleHandle( nullptr );
WNDCLASSEX wcx;
wcx.cbSize = sizeof(wcx);
wcx.style = 0;
wcx.lpfnWndProc = MyWinProc;
wcx.cbClsExtra = 0;
wcx.cbWndExtra = 0;
wcx.hInstance = hInstance;
wcx.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION); 
wcx.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wcx.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject( WHITE_BRUSH);
wcx.lpszMenuName = L"MainMenu";
wcx.lpszClassName = L"MyDummyClass";
wcx.hIconSm = (HICON)LoadImage(hInstance,
              MAKEINTRESOURCE(5),
              IMAGE_ICON,
              GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON),
              GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON),
              LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);

if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcx))
{
  throw "Bad 1.";
}

if (!this->CWnd::CreateEx(0, L"MyDummyClass", L"MyDummyWindow", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, HWND_MESSAGE, nullptr))
{
  throw "Bad 2.";
}
```

**Process B**

```
 auto myWnd = FindWindow( L"MyDummyClass");
```

Now the problem I have is if `process A` create the window before `OnInitDialog` is called then `process B` can find the window.

But if `process A` creates the window at any other time *after* the main window was created then `process B` cannot find the window any longer.

In both cases the message pump is called fine, the window is created as expected, I just cannot `FindWindow` when I create it *after* the main application is started.

Why would that be, and how can I work around that?

Comment: Why not pass the HWND or Class object to process B?

Comment: @JonnyHenly, what I mean is that, in either cases the window is created with no errors, but if created before the main window is created it can be 'found' but if created after the main dialog is created is can no longer be found.

Comment: @Joel the two processes are separate exes.

Comment: Can you use spyxx.exe to see if the window is created as expected? What is different in both cases?  Is it's parent the same in both instances?

Answer (score 0):

Use `FindWindowEx` instead:

> To find message-only windows, specify HWND_MESSAGE in the hwndParent
>   parameter of the FindWindowEx function. In addition, FindWindowEx
>   searches message-only windows as well as top-level windows if both the
>   hwndParent and hwndChildAfter parameters are NULL.

Comment: I just tried and the window is also not found using ``FindWindowEx``, it is 'found' if I create the window before the main dialog is created, but not after.